# C# - Dynamically drawing a table and contents results in extra row

Tags: c#, winforms

I am dynimically populating a panel with a table and adding some rows, columns, images and labes into the table based on the number of attached monitors. Each time the 'Monitors' panel is opened up, the dynimically added controls are removed and then re-added again in case any settings have been changed since it was last opened. When the panel is loaded for the first time, this is how it appears:

[image]

This is just how I want it to display. Both monitors detected and correct resolutions specified. Now, when the the Monitors panel is navigated away from, then switched back to (triggering the table contents to be removed and re-added), it displays with an extra row and old label like so:

[image]

No matter how many times the panel is navigated away from and back to, it always displays correctly the first time it's opened, then incorrectly any time after. Here is my code for populating the panel:

```
        public void monitorPanel_Paint()
        {
            // Remove existing monitor pictures
            foreach (Control item in monitorLayoutPanel.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
            {
                monitorLayoutPanel.Controls.Remove(item);
                item.Dispose();
            }

            // Remove existing monitor labels
            foreach (Control item in monitorLayoutPanel.Controls.OfType<Label>())
            {
                monitorLayoutPanel.Controls.Remove(item);
                item.Dispose();
            }

            // Get number of attached monitors
            int screens = Screen.AllScreens.Count();

            // Auto add a table to nest the monitor images and labels
            this.monitorLayoutPanel.Refresh();
            this.monitorLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Clear();
            this.monitorLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Clear();
            this.monitorLayoutPanel.ColumnCount = screens;
            this.monitorLayoutPanel.RowCount = 2;
            this.monitorLayoutPanel.AutoSize = true;

            int z = 0;
            foreach (var screen in Screen.AllScreens.OrderBy(i => i.Bounds.X))
            {                  

                var percent = 100f / screens;
                this.monitorLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, percent));

                PictureBox monitor = new PictureBox
                {
                    Name = "MonitorPic" + z,
                    Size = new Size(95, 75),
                    BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch,
                    BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.display_enabled,
                    Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None,                    
                };

                Label resolution = new Label
                {
                    Name = "MonitorLabel" + z,
                    TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
                    Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 10),
                    ForeColor = Color.Black,
                    BackColor = Color.Transparent,
                    Text = screen.Bounds.Width + "x" + screen.Bounds.Height,
                    Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None,
                };

                this.monitorLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(monitor, z, 0);
                this.monitorLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(resolution, z, 1);

                z++;    
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am surprised it isn't throwing an exception when you remove the controls from the `Controls` collection while enumerating it.  It's worth checking if that is causing the enumeration to get clobbered and causing you to skip removing some of the controls.  If that is the case, the solutions is capture a `List<Control>` of controls to remove while enumerating, then remove them all after enumerating it:

```
List<Control> controlsToRemove = new List<Control>();
foreach (Control item in monitorLayoutPanel.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>()) {
    controlsToRemove.Add(item);
}
foreach (Control item in monitorLayoutPanel.Controls.OfType<Label>()) {
    controlsToRemove.Add(item);
}
foreach (Control item in controlsToRemove) {
    monitorLayoutPanel.Controls.Remove(item);
    item.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: That did the trick, plus I've learned something! Thanks for your help. :)